# NOTICE: The example draw_triangulation_2 requires Qt and will not be compiled

Tags: qt, cmake, cgal

I install cgal and qt5 using vcpkg. Then I encountered this problem when try to use qt5.
[image]

It seems that cmake has found qt, but CGAL_Qt5_FOUND still returns false and I still got the message: NOTICE: The example draw_triangulation_2 requires Qt and will not be compiled.

env:
Operating system (Windows 10/64 bits):
Compiler: visual studio 2019
Specific flags used (if any):
CGAL version: 5.1
Boost version: 1.72.0

How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems that CGAL/Qt/GraphicsItem.h does not exist. How to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by reinstalling cgal using `vcpkg install cgal[qt]:x64-windows --recurse` instead of `vcpkg install cgal:x64-windows`.